# Validate user input with data in .txt file

Tags: python, file, text, verification

I have searched and searched and tried everything.  I am creating a game where the user will input a pre-assigned pin and I want to validate that pin against a .txt file in Python.  I have tried so many different lines of code and my result is either everything is valid or nothing is valid.  What am I doing wrong?
The pins are formatted on each line and are alpha numeric like this...

```
1DJv3Awv5
1DGw2Eql8
3JGl1Hyt7
2FHs4Etz4
3GDn9Buf8
1CEa9Aty0
2AIt9Dxz9
5DFu0Ati4
3AJu9Byi4
1EAm0Cfn1
3BEr0Gwk0
7JAf8Csf8
4HFu0Dlf4
```

Here is what I have:

```
user_input = input('Please enter your PIN: ')
if user_input in open("PINs.txt").read():
    print('Congratulations!  Click the button below to get your Bingo Number.')
else:
    print('The PIN you entered does not match our records.  Please check your PIN and try again.')
```

Comment: What is inside PINs.txt? Is it a list of pins separated on each line or via space or ...?

Comment: Need to see example pins and "PINs.txt" to be sure but your match is for simple text so will match a pin of "1" against file content of "1234" for example which is probably not what you want.
I suggest you spend some time with python tutorials generally before you go too much further. You can use simple databases or read/write yaml or json files for your data.

Comment: yeah... I guess that would help....  lol
Here is a sample
1DJv3Awv5
1DGw2Eql8
3JGl1Hyt7
2FHs4Etz4
3GDn9Buf8
1CEa9Aty0
2AIt9Dxz9
5DFu0Ati4
3AJu9Byi4
1EAm0Cfn1
3BEr0Gwk0
7JAf8Csf8
4HFu0Dlf4
each one is on it's own line.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and put that information in it where it can be formatted properly, not down here.

Comment: Thanks.  this is my first time asking a question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.readlines()`, this way you have to match the whole string:

```
user_input = input('Please enter your PIN: ') + "\n" # Adding \n to conform to readlines
if user_input in open("PINs.txt").readlines():
    print('Congratulations!  Click the button below to get your Bingo Number.')
else:
    print('The PIN you entered does not match our records.  Please check your PIN and try again.')
```

Small refactoring:

```
with open("PINs.txt") as pinfile:  # Make sure file is closed
  user_input = input('Please enter your PIN: ')
  for pin in pinfile:  # Iterate line by line, avoid loading the whole file into memory.
    if pin.rstrip() == user_input:  # Remove newline using .rstrip()
      print('Congratulations!  Click the button below to get your Bingo Number.')
      break
  else:  # Note the indentation, the 'else' is on the 'for' loop.
    print('The PIN you entered does not match our records.  Please check your PIN and try again.')
```

---

In fact, you can avoid using `.readlines()` altogether, this utilizes the fact file objects iterate over lines, and is better for memory too:

```
user_input = input('Please enter your PIN: ') + "\n" # Adding \n to conform to readlines
if user_input in open("PINs.txt"):
    print('Congratulations!  Click the button below to get your Bingo Number.')
else:
    print('The PIN you entered does not match our records.  Please check your PIN and try again.')
```

Comment: I had ``` .readlines():```  in there so many times but the thing that solved it was the ```+'\n'```
Thank you, thank you, thank you!